# mysql_num_rows cause internal server error

Tags: php, sql

I am checking whether a record is existed:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `collegeInfo` WHERE `name` = '$name' ";
$existed = mysqli_query($con, $query);
echo mysql_num_rows($existed);
```

the third line give me error:

> 500 - Internal server error.
>   There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: You need to add error checking. Try `$existed = 
mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));`

Comment: Also, when you get a 500 error, you should check the PHP error log on the server for the details.

Comment: Why dont you echo `mysqli_error($con)` ?

Answer (score 2):

You are using `mysql_num_rows() instead of [mysqli_num_rows()](http://www.php.net//manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)

Please use

```
echo mysqli_num_rows($existed);
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use [mysqli_num_rows()](http://www.php.net//manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) instead, change to:

```
echo mysqli_num_rows($existed);
```

Answer (score 0):

> You need to know, you should avoid using mysql and mysqli combined as you have done here:

```
 <?php
      echo mysql_num_rows($existed);
 ?>
```

It should be something like this

```
<?php
    echo mysqli_num_rows($existed);
?>
```

Try out this and it will work.